# Strange Error with Powershell when downloading files

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I got a very strange error when trying to install dnvm on powershell. Actually I get this error with any attempt to download anything, e.g. "wget" produces a similar error.

I thought first that I don't have the rights to execute but running this in an Administrator shell + I changed the Security Policy.

Then I figured that the PS doesn't have access to the internet, so I adjusted the Firewall and even added PS to the allowed programs. No luck!

Now the weird thing is that I can download files just fine via IE.

This is the error that I get

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:17
+ &{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.gith ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Anyone as an idea?

Also this is a machine running on AWS.

[image]

Comment: What does `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException` say?

Comment: `PS C:\temp> $Error[0].Exception.InnerException
An exception occurred during a WebClient request.`

Comment: Check if there's a certificate error on `raw.githubusercontent.com`, you might need to turn off strict certificate checking on your `WebClient` instance. Also check what's the cert, it's possible that you're being MITM'd, which is downright dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but first thing that comes to mind is proxy settings.

`System.Net.WebClient` does not automatically pick up IE's proxy configuration, but you should be able to force it to do so with:

```
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebProxy  = [System.Net.WebProxy]::GetDefaultProxy()
$WebClient.Proxy = $WebProxy
$WebClient.DownloadString($url)
```

or with your very compact syntax:

```
&{$Branch='dev';($w=New-Object Net.WebClient).Proxy=[Net.WebProxy]::GetDefaultProxy();iex $w.DownloadString($url)}
```

Comment: That's a pretty good shot, but this machine doesn't use a proxy at all.. I even knocked out the automatic proxy settings in IE and it's still useable (from IE).  This is my result for $WebProxy: `PS C:\temp> $WebProxy


Address               :
BypassProxyOnLocal    : False
BypassList            : {}
Credentials           :
UseDefaultCredentials : False
BypassArrayList       : {}
`